# ffmpeg , как снимать web камерой 24 кадра в секунду?

Tags: ffmpeg

Здравствуйте.

Хочу веб камерой снимать птиц, летают они быстро и нужно хотя бы 24-30 кадров в секунду. Применяю ffmpeg под Linux т.к. он может транслировать в реальном времени на сервер. Вроде, явно задаю количество кадров "-r 24 " , но fps опускается до 16.

ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -r 24 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy output.mkv

```
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 47949.605142, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, -4 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
File 'output.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, matroska, to 'output.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, q=2-31, -4 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 24 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  544 fps= 16 q=-1.0 Lsize=   43365kB time=00:00:36.20 bitrate=9811.0kbits/s speed=1.05x
```

ffmpeg -f v4l2 -s 640x480 -r 24 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy  output.mkv

```
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 48038.112804, bitrate: 117964 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 117964 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
File 'output.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, matroska, to 'output.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, q=2-31, 117964 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 24 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  785 fps= 16 q=-1.0 Lsize=  471039kB time=00:01:00.96 bitrate=63298.7kbits/s speed=1.22x
```

Что не так делаю?

Спасибо.

Comment: Все так. А кадров точно недостает? Просто дешевые вебкамеры часто удваивают кадры при плохом освещении. Попробуйте посветить лампочкой на 100 ватт - это творит чудеса даже с дешевыми вебками. Будет прирост кадров?

Comment: Спасибо @bukkojot . Дело действительно в этом. Положил под лампочку, fps поднялся до 24-30 , качество картинки ожидаемо улучшилось.

Comment: Странно, не должно быть больше, чем было запрошено. Регулировать fps при помощи лампочки - плохая практика. В профессиональной технике хотя бы можно задать время выдержки и к примеру, снимать лампочку (ее спираль) на 240 fps

Comment: Выдаёт сколько запрошено. Я менял -r от 24 до 50, максимум получилось fps=31.

Comment: А больше чипсет и не отдаст (если не расчитан на это), наверняка оно отдает 30, а 31 - это скорее ошибка округления или какой-то глюк.